# Import issue for falcon.responders in pyinstaller executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller, falcon

Having an import issue when running the exe (as onefile) created by pyinstaller I added 'falcon.responders' to the list of hidden imports. But still the import error when running the executable. What can be wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s2rdf.py", line 62, in <module>
    import morph_kgc
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "morph_kgc\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "morph_kgc\engine.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "morph_kgc\materializer.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "falcon\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "falcon\app.py", line 24, in init falcon.app
ImportError: cannot import name responders
[16196] Failed to execute script 's2rdf' due to unhandled exception!
```

Snippet from spec file

```
a = Analysis(
    ['s2rdf.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=['falcon.app_helpers','falcon.responders'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it was fixed by removing the last generated directories ("build" and "dist") and using this hidden import list:

```
hiddenimports=['falcon.app_helpers', 'xml.etree', 'falcon.responders', 'xml.etree.ElementTree']
```